# How do I convert a character field to date/time format in R?

Tags: r

This is what my data looks like. I would like to convert date and time columns to a time stamp and put it in a single column.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

```
    DATE        TIME    CLOSE   HIGH    LOW     OPEN    VOLUME
1   20150216    1520    2283.85 2284    2275.6  2275.6  48309
2   20150216    1530    2282    2284    2273.15 2283.85 108856
3   20150218    920     2276.1  2280.1  2260.6  2280.1  94279
4   20150218    930     2271.6  2277.95 2271    2276.1  65932
5   20150218    940     2270.35 2275    2268.2  2271.6  53595
6   20150218    950     2270.65 2271.2  2265.55 2270.5  34546
7   20150218    1000    2274.15 2274.25 2268.65 2270.6  35414
8   20150218    1010    2270.1  2274.9  2267.1  2274.25 37334
```

Comment: i dont know why the table format didnt come out right, here is a sample row  20150216   1520 2283.85 2284 2275.6 2275.6 48309

Comment: Do you need to convert this to `xts` or `zoo` object or simply a datetime column?

Comment: need to convert to xts yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
df$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(sprintf('%08d %04d', df$DATE, df$TIME),
                               format ='%Y%m%d %H%M')
df1 <- df[-(1:2)]
head(df1,2)
#    CLOSE HIGH     LOW    OPEN VOLUME            DateTime
#1 2283.85 2284 2275.60 2275.60  48309 2015-02-16 15:20:00
#2 2282.00 2284 2273.15 2283.85 108856 2015-02-16 15:30:00
```

#### Update

If you need to convert to `xts`, instead of creating a new column, we can remove the columns that are not needed (`df[-(1:2)]`) and specify `order.by` as the datetime vector ('indx')

```
library(xts)
indx <- as.POSIXct(sprintf('%08d %04d', df$DATE, df$TIME),
                               format ='%Y%m%d %H%M')
xt1 <- xts(df[-(1:2)], order.by=indx)
```

Comment: hey!! this works like a charm. dont know why i didnt think of this approach!.. thanks a ton.

Comment: hey!! this works like a charm. dont know why i didnt think of this approach!.. thanks a ton.

Comment: @DineshPatro No problem. I updated the post about converting the dataset to `xts` object.

Comment: this works but,  i need to be able to plot graph using quantmod. I could email you the details if you can share you email id

Comment: @DineshPatro Please do post that as a separate question.  You will get more answers here and in a faster way than asking a question privately